# how to set mysql2 timezone option to remove query warning

Tags: ruby, mysql2

I always get warning  when use mysql2 do query

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:463: warning: :database_timezone option must be :utc or :local - defaulting to :local
```

I did see a  option for   Timezones

Mysql2 now supports two timezone options:

```
  :database_timezone - this is the timezone Mysql2 will assume fields are already stored as, and will use this when creating the initial Time objects in ruby
  :application_timezone - this is the timezone Mysql2 will convert to before finally handing back to the caller
```

did any one know, how to usage, and where to set this option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

This is how I had fixed it:

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc
```